# 'Invalid_grant' response getting access token from reddit via OAuth2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, reddit, httparty

I'm able to login to my localhost site via reddit fine with OAuth2 and Rails, but when I try to make the subsequent (required) POST request to get the access token needed to make actual API calls I get the response '*invalid_grant*'. The OAuth reddit documentation ([here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2)) says invalid_grant means "The code has expired or already been used" .

But I'm sure it's not being re-used, I've moved the code around to be certain it can't be running twice and am monitoring the console. Changing other values in the POST request gives a 401 so the request itself is fine (I think).

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
@result = HTTParty.post("https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
  :body => { 
    :state => params[:state],
    :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/reddit/callback", 
    :code => params[:code],
    :grant_type => 'authorization_code',
  },
  :basic_auth=> { 
    username: ENV['REDDIT_KEY'], 
    password: ENV['REDDIT_SECRET']
  }
)

logger.info(@result.to_json)
```

Things I've tried:

- Quadruple checking all my reddit app details are correct like key, secret, redirect_uri
- Ensuring linux clock is synced with NTP
- Variations of code structure to ensure only being run once
- Different HTTP gems
- Endless roundabout fruitless trial and errors

If anyone has any ideas it would be massively appreciated. Spent the best part of a day on this and is getting a bit ridiculous. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you check the default value of `expires_in` parameter? In their CURL example they do get `"expires_in": 3600` but the default value might be too small. Are you sure as well that your timezone is the same as reddit’s one?

Comment: The expires_in is one of the values that should be returned from the POST I think rather than me providing it?

The timezone/time issue is looking to be the likely culprit I think, but I've installed the package to sync with NTP servers so not sure what else to do at this point on that side of things?

Comment: OK I deployed to heroku and have exact same issue, so I'm starting to think timezone issue is less likely?

Comment: Yes, heroku must have the correct TZ set.. BTW, did you tried their examples? Do they work as expected?

Comment: Interestingly this is in the response from reddit:

@headers={"date"=>["Mon, 14 Jul 2014 14:47:15 GMT"], 

But it is/was actually 15:47. This is same on local and heroku though

Comment: 15:47 GMT? Try to set the time/zone to be the same as @reddit, despite the correct value is (don’t forget to turn off your NTP sync.) This should help.

Comment: Thanks for all your help today. Sadly manually setting my time didn't fix it, but it seems crazy that reddit would force all servers who use their oauth to have the same timezone as them (was worth a try though for sure!). Did you mean their CURL examples?

Comment: Actually CURL works (had to use the account who created the app). So I don't think it is my system.

Answer (score 0):

OK it's working. Wow this embarrassing... so the omniauth-reddit gem I am using actually gets the token for you as well as the authorisation itself - that whole additional step is simply not necessary using that gem so it was in fact being used more than once hence the invalid_grant.

What's worse is I saw the 'token' in the response earlier today and tested a direct API call using it, but must have messed up the syntax in some way and as the format wasn't what I was expecting (plus there was an 'authorization token' and an 'access token' referred to in the guide I was using so assumed it was the former) and so I went on a wild goose chase all day.